# How to truncate a Tumblr post in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically. I'm building a Tumblr theme with flipping panels based on a site I made for a hackathon. Tumblr will only give me the contents of a text post as a massive string. But I want it truncated to like 200 characters so the contents will all fit on one "panel".

(The URL for the theme at the moment is http://jackwantshugs.tumblr.com/ and the text post is the one on the top left.)

I'm not asking how to simply truncate a post. I want to know how to just include a script at the bottom of the document that will truncate all posts with the class "textposttext" Can anyone help?

Comment: `"string".substring(0, 200);` or `"string".substr(0, 200);`

Comment: use `substring` method

Comment: see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for

```
string.substring(from, to)
```

in other words use it like this

```
var myString = "really long string and things and what not";
console.log(myString.subString(0, 6));  ///will log "really"
```

You can read more **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)**.

Comment: Thank you. I will take that under advice